# C# script to remotely query data from a calling software and update local database

Tags: c#, mysql

I will give an example:

1. Salesman makes calls using a calling software (leaddesk).
2. During call salesman get information from prospects and updated company information in the calling software (leaddesk), for example address.
3. Some hours later your C# script queries data from the calling software (leaddesk) database of the newly and updated information of contacted data.
4. Finally this data will be updated/inserted in your local DB.

Question. How can I achieve this in C#?
Attach is an image of what it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mXct.png

Comment: ... and what's your question?

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ how can I achieve this ? I was only able to made a script that collects data from a excel file to to local database but for this, data has to be from the calling software then to my local database.

Comment: I really don't understand your whole question
If you could post some sort of a diagram that would help